# Calculate dynamic height of uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios6

I'm searching too many questions related to increasing height of `UITableViewCells` but I can't get exactly what I want.

I have to calculate dynamic height of `UITableViewCell`. But, problem is in my cell there is a dynamic number of buttons, ranging from 1 to 100. I don't know how many buttons will show beforehand. So how can we calculate the height?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the height of the TableView or TableViewCell ??

Comment: did you try heightForRowAtIndexPath method for calculate height

Comment: When you don't know how many buttons there will be in the cell you can't calculate the cell height. You need at least some info.

Comment: but that buttons also dynamic means, my task is dynamic and number of buttons isequal to task number

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do is that you can have a global variable, for ex: cellHeight, and then change the cellHeight dynamically when you are customising your cell.

finally, return the cellHeight

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return cellHeight;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

There are **Two Way** for get size of `UITableViewCell`

```
1) cell.bounds.size.height 
2) cell.contentView.frame.size.height
```

It depending on which you actually need.